# Stone compactification vs initial/final structure as in Bourbaki

Tags: general-topology, category-theory

Does the Stone-Cech compactification resemble final structure (such as quotient topology) as described in Bourbaki's Theory of Sets Ch.IV? I feel so since continuous $f:X \rightarrow K$ implies the existence of continuous $F:\beta X \rightarrow K$. Not sure I am on the right track though (probably not, but why?) I am not familiar with category theory so my feeling could be obviously wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not be what you're asking, but there *is* a sense in which the Stone-Cech compactification is "final" like the quotient topology... Unfortunately, the language is entirely muddled up because the [initial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_and_terminal_objects) structure category theoretically corresponds to having the most open sets you're allowed. Which means you're the biggest element in the lattice of possible topologies, and so you're called [final](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_topology).

Dually, of course, the topology a category theorist would call [terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_and_terminal_objects) or final is exactly the structure which is traditionally called [initial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_topology). The language is entirely backwards. (If you'll continue indulging my rant -- this has permeated into the language of [topologically concrete categories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/topological+concrete+category) which is *endlessly* confusing).

To make the answer as reader-friendly as possible, I'll specify when I mean

- categorical-initial (there is a map *to* every other object)
- bourbaki-final (the same as above)
- categorical-final (there is a map *from* every other object)
- bourbaki-initial (same as above)

You need a mild technical assumption on $X$ ([complete regularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tychonoff_space)), which I'll assume from here on out.

---

The reason you're seeing a similarity between $\beta X$ and the quotient topology is because they're both categorical-initial. Unfortunately, the quotient topology is called bourbaki-final, and $\beta X$ is typically called the "biggest" compactification... So at least they're both backwards.

To see why, we define a partial order on compactifications by setting

$$\alpha_2 \leq \alpha_1$$

whenever for some continuous $f$

[image: poset structure on compactifications]

That's not a typo: $\alpha_2 \leq \alpha_1$. The language is backwards.

If you like, this is the *opposite* poset structure that comes from the slice category under $X$. Since we're restricting attention to compactifications, and thus compact hausdorff spaces, we see $\alpha_1 \leq \alpha_2 \leq \alpha_1 \implies \alpha_1 X \cong \alpha_2 X$. So we really do get a poset.

Now one can show that $\beta$ is maximal in this poset. That is, it's categorical-initial in the category of compactifications under $X$ in a way that's entirely analogous to the quotient topology being categorical-initial in the category of "topologies identifying certain points" under $X$.

---

Rather interestingly, the one point compactification (when it exists), is smallest in this partial order. That is, the one point compactification is categorical-terminal, and is thus analogous to bourbaki-initial topologies in a similar sense.
You can find a proof of this [here](https://www.math.wustl.edu/%7Efreiwald/ch10.pdf).

If you want an excellent blog post with proofs of the claims I glossed over, you should read [this](https://dantopology.wordpress.com/2012/09/24/stone-cech-compactification-is-maximal/) post from Dan Ma's topology blog. (You'll also notice I stole the above image from this site...). The whole series on the Stone-Cech compactification is good. In particular, though, you might find [this](https://dantopology.wordpress.com/2012/09/21/two-characterizations-of-stone-cech-compactification/) post worthwhile too.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: It absolutely helps. You actually answered not only I explicitly asked, but also something I was unable to ask due to my lack of understanding in this field. It will take me a bit of time to read through your own explanation and what you refer to in the links, and assimilate them.  A quick question on your answer: did you mean that "quotient topology being categorical-initial in the category of 'topologies identifying certain points' under X" as you wrote? If so, in which sense? In the sense like specifying convergence classes (such as filters/UFs concerging to points in X)?

Comment: Of course! Take your time. Once you feel like this answered your question, though, you should accept it so that other users know how to spend their time

Comment: Also by "quotient topologies are category-initial", i meant they are characterized by maps FROM them. See for instance [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_space_(topology)#Properties) wikipedia article. It turns out that these kinds of "universal properties" can _always_ be phrased as being an initial object in a certain category. The exact construction is a little bit finicky, which is why I didn't include it, but you can find it in most category theory books

Comment: See [here](https://jeremykun.com/2013/05/24/universal-properties/) for instance, on building a category in which the quotient object is category-initial

Comment: thanks for additional clarification. Though I meant to ask to clarify why you said "... topologies **identifying certain points**". Or maybe "identifying certain points" is just a way of saying quotient set/space in the sense that each equivalence class identifies certain points, but nothing specifically related to the topologies we are talking about?

Comment: Yeah, I'm exactly talking about how equivalence relations identify certain points. You can then topologize the space of equivalence classes in a variety of ways, and you want to pick the way which is "best" in a certain sense. That sense is measured by the universal property i mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Not really, it's functor from $\mathtt{Tych}$ to $\mathtt{CompHaus}$, so a map $f: X \to Y$ between Tychonoff spaces induces a unique $\beta f: \beta X \to \beta Y$ in a functiorial way (preserving compositions and identities). It is also has extension property as in AR (absolute retracts) theory.

And with a final or initial structure you start with a set and some maps, while with $\beta X$ you start with $X$ and construct *both* a new set and a new topology. There is no map.

Both things being "categorical" doesn't mean they're related.

Comment: Sure, thanks. There is a similar explanation https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Stone-Cech+compactification. But still, can we interpret it as a sort of final structure? If we cannot, what's the critical reason?

Comment: @ALife Well, $\beta X$ does not have underlying set $X$, which is inconsistent with the usual notion of final structure.